# node js chat server not working on different machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, localhost

I have made a node js and socket io (very basic) for my game on my local system

I start/log into my game through localhost/Gamename/filename no problem and load the chat index.html file into a div and it works no problem, messages are seen by 2 different browsers on my computer and i see the names of whoever is logged into my game from that browser when they send a message.

However when i go to go on chrome on my phone or another machine ( which uses 1**.***.*.*/gamename/filename ip from my computer that works) it doesnt work at all. I can send a message and it doesnt populate on my working computer chat box system.

Im not sure how to make it work so that my working computers current node js socket io chat system will work with any machine so i can see anyone messaging from any computer or machine.

EDITED:
here is my pages and code:

server.js:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(3000, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('new-user', name => {
    users[socket.id] = name
    //socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name)
  })
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', { message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    //socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
  })
})
```

Script.js:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

const name = sessionStorage.getItem("chatUsername");

appendMessage('You joined')
socket.emit('new-user', name)

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
})

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
})

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const message = messageInput.value
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
  messageInput.value = ''
})

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
  messageElement.innerText = message
  messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}
```

Index.html (this page is loaded into the div to show chatbox on my game)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Chat App</title>

  <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #message-container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    #message-container div {
      background-color: #CCC;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    #message-container div:nth-child(2n) {
      background-color: #FFF;
    }

    #send-container {
      position: fixed;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 1200px;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    #message-input {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="message-container"></div>
  <form id="send-container">
    <input type="text" id="message-input">
    <button type="submit" id="send-button">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

can you please help me, ive looked and watched several videos and webpages and nothing has helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could be a firewall issue

Comment: @Bravo edited the question to show code   hope that helps some

Comment: how do you think `const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')` would try to connect to anything but localhost? `localhost` is the *local host* - i.e. the machine on which you are

Comment: @Bravo how do i change it to allow connections from other devices?

Comment: change what? the server or the client?

Comment: change the server to accept different clients  including ones from other devices.

Comment: but your client code opens `localhost` - you need to change what the *client* opens

Comment: okay,  my local computer uses localhost but my other clients on my local network use the ip address   i.e  192.***.*.*/gamename/filename.php

Comment: oh, your code suggests otherwise, sorry - well, as I said yesterday, it could be a firewall blocking the port on the "local computer" - i.e the one that is running the server code

Comment: how would i be able to tell